# SwiftUI how to make List and Section transparent

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make a list that looks something like this:

[image]

However no matter what I try, I can't figure out how to make both the List and the Sections have a `.clear` background, and it currently looks like this:

[image]

I have tried adding `.background(Color.clear)` to both the List and Section, with no luck.
When I use any other color than clear, it does change just fine. But it seems like there's something "behind" that background color that makes it still show white and gray underneath...

How do I change this list to be completely clear?

Here is my current failed attempt:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(uniqueEntries, id: \.self) { category in
                    Section(header: HStack {
                        Text(category)
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                        Spacer()
                    }
                        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                        .background(Color.clear)
                    ) {
                        ForEach(self.entriesCollatedByCategory[category]!) { entry in
                            ExpenseRow(entry: entry)
                                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                            
                                
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Image("tempGradientBackground")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill))
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Budget"))
        }.background(Color.clear)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the init add the appearance style

```
init() {
    UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    UITableView.appearance().sectionIndexBackgroundColor = .clear
}
```

And you need to change the `ListStyle` aswell to make the SectionBackground transparent

```
.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
```

**Edit:** Even better to use InsetGroupedList in your case. Thanks to pawello22222

```
.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
```

Comment: Actually it can be `.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())` - it should match OP requirements more (at least I think so).

Comment: @pawello2222 Yes, that's way better. Thanks!! I will edit it

Comment: Thank you so much! This is my first Swift app, did not know how to override defaults, so this was super helpful!

Comment: as of iOS 16, hacking around with the appearance proxies no longer works.

Answer (score 3):

> But it seems like there's something "behind" that background color
> that makes it still show white and gray underneath...

Try removing `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell` background colors as well:

```
UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
```